# List asp.net topics for interview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having 3 years of experience in asp.net. I need to list down topics that are related to web development

I have listed the following topics. Please add your topics if in case i have missed

A.OOPS

1. Classes
2. Objects
3. Polymorphism
4. Encapsulation
5. Abstraction
6. Inheritance
7. Interface
8. Abstract class / virtual cass
9. Access Modifiers
10. Overloading vs Overriding

B. C#

1. Boxing-Unboxing
2. Delegate- event
3. Collections
4. Generics
5. Value Type vs Reference Type

C. ASP.NET Topics

1. Authentication and Authorization
2. state Management
3. XML/XSL/XSLT
4. Web Services
5. Array List, Hashtable, Generices
6. Themes, Skins and Master Pages
7. Remoting
8. Reflection
9. Serialization
10. Caching
11. Threading
12. Localization
13. HTTP Handlers / HTTP Module
14. ASP.NET Entity f/w
15. JSON

D. Designing

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. XTML (Also Themes, skins and master pages)

E. Advanced ASP.NET Concepts

1. WCF
2. WPF
3. JQUERY
4. Silverlight
5. AJAX
6. DNN
7. Axure
8. MVC

F. ADO.NET

H. SQL Server

1. Normalization
2. SP/ Functions (differnce), views
3. Triggers

**PLEASE POST THE TOPICS THAT I HAVE MISSED OUT**

Comment: Please ask questions about programming, not hiring interviews.

Comment: Sorry, these are programming questions

Comment: 21 views and 2 comments... :-( i expect more response

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good list, but worth knowing about the following too I reckon

LINQ 
O/R Mapping - eg Nhibernate
Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control - eg. Windsor / structureMap
Design patterns - eg MVC MVP SOA etc
SQL Full-text search 
SQL 2008 new features- eg CTEs
New features in asp.net / C# 4.0

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention LINQ

Comment: Could also add general JavaScript to that list above too.

Comment: for 1 year experienced , what topics do you expects to know?? @Dave

Comment: for 1 year experienced , what topics do you expects to know?? @SmithPascalJr.